# How can I create an Odoo/OpenERP product instance in Python, interactively?

Tags: python, odoo

I want to interactively create new Odoo/OpenERP product. I got as far as importing the addon:

```
python

>>> import openerp
>>> openerp.tools.config.parse_config(['--addons-path=addons'])
>>> from openerp.addons.product import product
>>> p = new product.product_product()
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

>>> p = product.product_product()
>>> type(p)
NoneType   # no luck here either

# And then there is...

>>> product.product_product.create()

TypeError: unbound method create() must be called with product_product instance as first argument (got nothing instead)

# Ok I get that, but how do I create a product_product instance?

# And this one is not very clear either:

>>> product.product_product.create_instance()

TypeError: create_instance() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given)
```

But the `create_instance` docstring is not very helpful unfortunately and `ack-grep create_instance` doesn't give me any results inside the addons directory.

I've been looking for good `osv` (the Odoo ORM) examples, but not much luck there thus far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ERPpeek](https://github.com/tinyerp/erppeek) makes this a lot easier.

```
$ sudo pip install erppeek
$ erppeek --server ... -d ... -u ... -p ... --verbose

>>> prod = model('product.product')
>>> prod.create({ 'name': 'Test Produkt'})
```

[image: ERPpeek screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

OpenERP's "ORM" is a little bit tricky, and poorly documented.

However, we can read sources and understand, what kind of magic to expect:

```
# 1. Set modules path, like done above. 
import openerp
openerp.tools.config.parse_config(['--addons-path=addons'])

# 2. Obtain cursor and pool of models. 
db, pool = openerp.pooler.get_db_and_pool('dbname')

# 3. Import the model, that you want to create, like done above. 
from openerp.addons.product import product

# 4. Initialize database cursor
curr = db.cursor()

# 5. Create an instance of the model
p = product.product_product.create_instance(pool, curr)

# 6. Now create a model with values
product.product_product.create(p, curr, 1, {'name':'Test2'})
```

Comment: I run into `TypeError: The model "product.product" specifies an unexisting parent class "mail.thread" You may need to add a dependency on the parent class' module.` Tried `from openerp.addons.mail import mail` in vain.

Comment: @KasperSouren, it means, that pool of models initialized incorrectly. What's the output of `db, pool = openerp.pooler.get_db_and_pool('dbname')
`?

Comment: `db, pool = openerp.pooler.get_db_and_pool('dbname')` was very slow, but it's faster now, not sure why. `db, pool` gives me `(<openerp.sql_db.Connection at 0x2aa0850>, <openerp.modules.registry.Registry at 0x2a7fa90>)` (Still getting the same error with this.) (Shall I turn this into a separate question?)

Comment: @KasperSouren, here is example of pooler output http://pastebin.com/zNdTXiPk.. Do you see same message, that about 30 base modules loaded?

Comment: How do I get that output?

Comment: I started http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24757276/how-can-i-make-sure-openerp-pooler-get-db-and-pooldbname-is-working-fine

Answer (score 0):

One more way to work with OpenERP/Odoo orm interactively and remotely is to use [Openerp Proxy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/openerp_proxy/) lib/cli. It has IPython shell, and tools to work with OpenERP/Odoo data interactively.

In Your at first install and run openerp_proxy shell:

```
$ pip install openerp_proxy
$ openerp_proxy
```

then connect to database:

```
>>> db = session.connect()  # all connection related info will be asked here
```

and create product:

```
>>> product_obj = db['product.product']  # get product model
>>> product_id = product_obj.create({'name': 'My cool product'})
```

(for more info read the [docs](http://pythonhosted.org/openerp_proxy/))

(And in future versions some syntax sugar will be implemented)